# Advanced parameter usage

Tags: javascript, parameters, mootools, anonymous-function

```
//This is the function that will run every time a new item is added or the 
//list is sorted.
var showNewOrder = function() {
    //This function means we get serialize() to tell us the text of each 
    //element, instead of its ID, which is the default return.
    var serializeFunction = function(el) { return el.get('text'); };
    //We pass our custom function to serialize();
    var orderTxt = sort.serialize(serializeFunction);
    //And then we add that text to our page so everyone can see it.
    $('data').set('text', orderTxt.join(' '));
};
```

full code is at http://demos.mootools.net/Dynamic.Sortables

```
var serializeFunction = function(*el*) { return el.get('text'); };
var orderTxt = sort.serialize(serializeFunction*(el)*);
```

compare the codes.

Is el being passed or not? what is going on???

I want to learn advanced parameter usage.

If not declaring functions like `function name(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3...)`.
If not calling functions like `name(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3...)`.
If parameters aren't variables.

If declaring functions like `function(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3...)`.
If calling functions like `variable(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3...)`.
If parameters are objects.

I'm interested.

You probably have a bookmark with the lessons in which I'm interested... please, share!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value assigned to "serializeFunction" is actually an anonymous function, you can see it like a *pointer* or reference to a function, "el" is simply a declared input parameter that will be used then that function will be called.

Looking at the [original code](http://demos.mootools.net/demos/Dynamic.Sortables/demo.js) of the one that was posted, the call of the `sort.serialize` function, receives only the function as a parameter, the "serializeFunction" is not being invocated, it's only passed as an argument.

So, the serialize function that receives the reference of the function passed as a parameter it will be in charge of execute it internally.

Comment: If I had to invoke serializeFunction, would I need to pass el to it?

Comment: I think that understanding how JavaScript Closures work (http://is.gd/1dUUH), will clear all your doubts.

Comment: Yes, you should invoke the function with the value of the el parameter: serializeFunction(myEl);

Answer (score 0):

This is a lambda expression like.

```
sort.serialize()
```

accept the **function** as parameter, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

The first code is probably correct.

In JavaScript, functions are stored in variables just as any other value (as you see with `serializeFunction`), and `sort.serialize` only takes a reference to `serializeFunction`. Then `serializeFunction` is called from `sort.serialize` with the current element (`el`).

The second code would send an `undefined` value to the `serializeFunction` (since `el` has not been defined in that scope) which would throw an error. Even if `el` was defined, `sort.serialize` expects a reference to a function, not a value.